# BottomNavigation in react native

Tags: react-native, bottomnavigationview

I create a bottom navigation in my react native project. But its not looking good in Iphone10.
It showing extra space in bottom.Please help me how to resolve this.
This is below code i tried.

```
  import BottomNavigation,{FullTab} from 'react-native-material-bottom-navigation' 

      <BottomNavigation
          onTabPress={newTab => this.clickoftab(newTab.key)}
          renderTab={this.renderTab}
          tabs={this.tabs}
        />
```

My render tab part is this

```
        renderTab = ({ tab, isActive }) => {
         return (
          <FullTab
          style={{padding:0,margin:0}}
          key={tab.key}
          isActive={isActive}
          label={tab.label}
          renderIcon={this.renderIcon(tab.icon)} 
          />
       )
     }
```

This is my output which i want to change in bottom navigation

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding padding and margin 0 in your renderTab function

Comment: I have edit my render tab part as per your suggestion but still its not working @Ammar Tariq

Comment: @Suarabh Mistry Thank you for your edit

Comment: Are you rendering your app in safe area view?

Comment: yes i am rendering safe area view @Ammar Tariq

Comment: remove safeareaview it worked for me

Comment: But if i removed safeareaview my whole app design will misplaced.

Comment: And i already design app as per safeareaview so at this moment i can't remove safeareaview otherwise i need to redesign whole app

Comment: what safe area does is it add margins in iphone to avoid the line that is why you are seeing this white space, another solution that I came across is adding a backgroundColor

Comment: i already define background color #ffffff

Comment: change it to green that you are using

Comment: if i did green then also space will be there, see above image there is extra green space thats i want to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of your architecture app, if like you say in the comments, if you use `SafeAreaView` I thought in create the `BottomNavigation` at the same `level` of the `SafeAreaView`. I mean (sorry my english), I suppose that you have the `SafeAreaView` in your "Father file" like `App.js`. So, at the same time you can manage the `BottomNavigation` from there. So, you could put `SafeAreaView` inside of `BottomNavigation` making `BottomNavigation` the father of your app I guess. I don't know if I am explaining well. The conclusion could be that

> just apply SafeArea To things that are inside of Navigation instead of
>   full application.

Comment: Yes it does. I used it first component by component like a dumb haha, then I ported to the whole application.

Comment: As I understand, SafeAreaView is like a protection for each component that is inside if itself to the overflow of iPhone 10